# How to install Ceilometer and Gnocchi on different servers?

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

I have an Openstack environment with 3 controller servers HA with Pacemaker.
I'm trying to install Ceilometer on one controller, due to the high load of gnocchi I want to install gnocchi on a separate server.
first, I wonder if there is a way to install gnocchi on an independent server and how to connect it to ceilometer?

second, what is the proposed solution to install gnocchi alongside 3 controller servers that are configured HA with pacemaker.

any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Regarding the first question, I think you only need to ensure that the correct gnocchi endpoints are registered in the service catalog. Then configure `gnocchi://` as a publisher in `pipeline.yaml`. I don't understand the second question.